# Make each part of picture a button

Tags: html, css

I'm making a userscript for a game that allows a player to choose a flair from a menu. I have a picture that contains each flair that looks like this:

[image: flairs]

Without separating each flair into its own image, how can I make a layer of buttons on top of each flair in a sort of grid-like fashion? That way when the user presses the button on top of a flair, I can know which button was pressed and get the necessary information to select it.

I'm thinking of putting the picture in an `<img>` tag and making a table that lies right over the image, but I'm worried about how to line up the table correctly.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to use a sprite map

## Quick example

Pluck the only part of the image that you want out of it.

**CSS like this**

```
#home {
    width: 46px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url(img_navsprites.gif) 0 0;
}
```

**HTML like this**

```
<div id="home"></div>
```

You'll define a css id or class for each image in `img_navsprites.gif`

## Reduced CSS example

This way we reduce the required CSS (at the cost of more verbose html).  Bootstrap does similar things with glyphicons.

**CSS**

```
.sprite {
    // Assuming equal width and height of all sprites in the map
    width: 46px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url(img_navsprites.gif);
}

.sprite-first {
    background-position: 0 47px;
}
.sprite-second {
    background-position: 0 93px;
}
.sprite-third{
    background-position: 0 139px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="sprite sprite-second"></span>
```

**Source**

[CSS Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Comment: Is this a bad answer, or better as a comment? (Got a downvote)

Comment: No clue who downvoted it, I'm looking at the w3page right now

Comment: Cool, hope it helps :)  I've updated my answer with more details / thoughts for easy reference.

Comment: If you have time, take a look on [Compass CSS Image Sprites](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/), this is very helpful, you can put all small images file in a folder, compass help you create an image for all of them, also write down css code for sprites too.

Comment: Ah nice, always good to have an open source and tested solution for non-trivial use cases.  I've been meaning to add Sass to my dev stack, one more motivation to do it.